# Помогите с прожорливой памятью

Tags: php, phpexcel

Люди добрые помогите решить проблему. 
Через библиотеку чтения Excel файлов считываю большой файл и память на сервере сжирает данный скрипт,как освобождать память при каждом цикле ? Ну или как решить по другому ???

```
    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('test.csv');

    Foreach($excel ->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $lists[] = $worksheet->toArray();
    }

foreach($lists as $list){
 echo '<table border="1">';
 // Перебор строк
 foreach($list as $row){
   echo '<tr>';
   // Перебор столбцов
   foreach($row as $col){
     echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
 }
 echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Не использовать эту библиотеку, к сожалению других выходов нет.

Comment: зачем вообще использовать PHPExcel для вывода csv файла?

Comment: CSV - текстовый формат, его легко можно прочитать вручную, без библиотек. собственно PHP сам по себе для этого и предназначен в основном.

Answer (score 0):

Для обработки больших файлов (больше чем доступная память) нужно эти файлы не целиком считывать, а обрабатывать построчно:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<table>";
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo "<td>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Более подробно смотрите на http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$lines = file('test.csv'); //Читает содержимое файла и помещает его в массив

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach($lines as $line){
  $list = explode(";", $line); //Разбивает строку с помощью разделителя

  foreach($list as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    // Перебор столбцов
    foreach($row as $col){
      echo '<td>'.$col.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}

echo '</table>';
```

Такой код более читабельный. Подобное я использовал на csv файлах размером более 20мб.